# MSQLI Having Trouble with num_rows

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having trouble returning the number of rows. I want my code to check if a username exists, and if it does then return an error. The way I am going about this is if num_rows returns a number larger than 0. I haven't implemented that part yet, I am just trying to get it to return the number of rows right now. Here is my current code:

```
    $hostname = ''; //SET SERVER/HOSTNAME
    $dbusername = ''; //SET DATABASE USERNAME
    $dbname = ''; //SET DATABASE NAME
    $dbpassword = ''; //SET DATABASE USERNAME
    $link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname); 

    if (!$link)
    { 
        $systemerror = 'Connect Error' . mysqli_connect_errno()  . mysqli_connect_error();
        $error = "there has been an error";
}


$sql = "SELECT username FROM affiliates WHERE username = $username"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);

    if (!result) 
    { 
        $error = "There was an error with our system. Please contact All Choice Dental or wait a few minutes. Thank you.";
        goto error;
    }
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;   
    echo $row_cnt;
```

I don't even get zero back for num_rows, so something has to be wrong. I know I can connect to the database, because I can Insert rows using the same connection.

Comment: Do you have error_reporting enabled? Not seeing that `echo` implies you may have an earlier fatal error. I note first that `$username` should probably be single-quoted in the SQL.  Perhaps you aren't using PHP 5.3 and don't have `goto`.

Comment: Anyway, `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` ...always do this in development.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're mixing MySQLi OOP and Procedural - which is bad coding style.

To get the number of rows procedurally, use `mysqli_num_rows($result)`

Comment: Forgot to mention quotes as @MarcB did. I've updated the answer to mention that it's simply bad coding style.

Comment: Ok, so if i change it to $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result); Then i get the following error: mysqli_num_rows() [function.mysqli-num-rows]: Function cannot be used with MYSQL_USE_RESULT

Answer (score 1):

`$username` is never defined in your code, so the query comes out as

```
SELECT username FROM ... username =
```

As well, since a username is likely to be a string, you're also lacking quotes around that variable, so even if it was set, the query would still be wrong. e.g.

```
$username = 'fred';
```

would produce

```
SELECT username FROM affiliates WHERE username = fred
```

and you're not likely to have a `fred` field in your affiliates table. The field should be quoted:

```
SELECT username FROM ... WHERE username = '$username';
```

and you should seriously consider using prepared statements instead, as this sort of construct is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Sorry, yes $username is defined earlier in the code. It gets it VIA post from the form page I have.

Comment: Ok, so if i change it to $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result); Then i get the following error: mysqli_num_rows() [function.mysqli-num-rows]: Function cannot be used with MYSQL_USE_RESULT